# Magento 2.3.4 BUG Undefined Offset Error

Tags: attributes, magento2.3.4, bug

I am using magento 2.3.4 ver, i am getting following error if i try to apply filter,

[image]

Error:

**Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: -298 in /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm.php on line 302**

How to solve this issue? Is it a configuration error?

Comment: On a quick search it seems to be a Magento bug.
Here's the link, maybe you can find something useful there https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22792

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been around on and off across magneto versions. if you run the below patch your issue should be resolved

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/db69693bd929bd8665015ff6d9b6a3845584aa0b.patch

if you need any information on how to run patches in Magento 2 please refer to

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching.html

Answer (score 0):

Almost certain that your theme rewrites some layered functions and should be missing some function parameters.

Probably the modules themes are outdated or not adjusted to your current magento version.

Try to update your theme package.

Comment: I just purchased the theme from https://themeforest.net/item/fastest-magento-2-themes-magento-212-magento-19-multipurpose-responsive-theme-10-design/16178989/comments?page=88&filter=all#comment_25096792

Comment: What should i ask them?

Comment: First you must check if your theme up-to-date.
If not, create a dev environment and test upgrading.

If you don't want to do that, you must start tracking the function doing per example a grep via ssh and checking the routes of the function.