# Magento 2.3 - How to handle Preference Error - Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: module, magento2.3.4, bug, preference

I am using Magento 2.3.4 small bug in it ([LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/321321/57334)) then Update the following code

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/db69693bd929bd8665015ff6d9b6a3845584aa0b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm.php

For testing, if i apply code directly to **vendor/magento/framework/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm.php** bug solved.

For avoiding conflicts i am trying to use **Preference**,

**app/code/Gta/Solver/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm" type="Gta\Solver\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Gta/Solver/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Gta_Solver" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Gta/Solver/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Gta_Solver',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Gta/Solver/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm.php**

**Code :** https://paste.ofcode.org/eggKeUuvGeE3izxV6K9rUC

After creating preference i am getting error, i am using same code what i used for the test.

Error : 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\Improved

NOTE : I did di compile and clear the cache still i am facing an error.

How to solve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this class

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Gta\Solver\Search\Dynamic;

use Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\IntervalInterface;

/**
 * Algorithm for layer value filter
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @api
 */
class Algorithm extends \Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm
{
    /**
     * Minimal possible value
     */
    const MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE = .01;

    /**
     * Rounding factor coefficient
     */
    const TEN_POWER_ROUNDING_FACTOR = 4;

    /**
     * Interval deflection coefficient
     */
    const INTERVAL_DEFLECTION_LIMIT = .3;

    /**
     * Standard normal distribution's  a/2 quantile
     * Depends on predefined a. In case of a=0.05
     */
    const STANDARD_NORMAL_DISTRIBUTION = 1.96;

    /**
     * Min and Max number of intervals
     */
    const MIN_INTERVALS_NUMBER = 2;

    const MAX_INTERVALS_NUMBER = 10;

    /**
     * Upper values limit
     *
     * @var null|float
     */
    protected $_upperLimit = null;

    /**
     * Lower values limit
     *
     * @var null|float
     */
    protected $_lowerLimit = null;

    /**
     * Number of segmentation intervals
     *
     * @var null|int
     */
    protected $_intervalsNumber = null;

    /**
     * Upper limits of skipped quantiles
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_skippedQuantilesUpperLimits = [];

    /**
     * Total count of values
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_count = 0;

    /**
     * Current quantile interval
     *
     * @var array [from, to]
     */
    protected $_quantileInterval = [0, 0];

    /**
     * Values of current quantile
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_values = [];

    /**
     * Max value
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected $_maxValue = 0;

    /**
     * Min value
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected $_minValue = 0;

    /**
     * Last value query limiter
     *
     * @var array [index, value]
     */
    protected $_lastValueLimiter = [null, 0];

    /**
     * Set lower and upper limit for algorithm
     *
     * @param null|float $lowerLimit
     * @param null|float $upperLimit
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm
     */
    public function setLimits($lowerLimit = null, $upperLimit = null)
    {
        $this->_lowerLimit = empty($lowerLimit) ? null : (double)$lowerLimit;
        $this->_upperLimit = empty($upperLimit) ? null : (double)$upperLimit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set statistics
     *
     * @param float $min
     * @param float $max
     * @param float $standardDeviation
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStatistics($min, $max, $standardDeviation, $count)
    {
        $this->_count = $count;
        $this->_minValue = $min;
        $this->_maxValue = $max;
        $valueRange = $max - $min;
        if ($count < 2 || $valueRange <= 0) {
            //Same value couldn't be separated with several intervals
            $this->_intervalsNumber = 1;

            return $this;
        }

        if ($standardDeviation <= 0) {
            $intervalsNumber = pow(10, self::TEN_POWER_ROUNDING_FACTOR);
        } else {
            $intervalsNumber = $valueRange * pow($count, 1 / 3) / (3.5 * $standardDeviation);
        }
        $this->_intervalsNumber = max(ceil($intervalsNumber), self::MIN_INTERVALS_NUMBER);
        $this->_intervalsNumber = (int)min($this->_intervalsNumber, self::MAX_INTERVALS_NUMBER);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate separators, each contains 'from', 'to' and 'count'
     *
     * @param IntervalInterface $interval
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function calculateSeparators(IntervalInterface $interval)
    {
        $result = [];
        $lastCount = 0;
        $intervalFirstValue = $this->_minValue;
        $lastSeparator = $this->_lowerLimit === null ? 0 : $this->_lowerLimit;

        for ($intervalNumber = 1; $intervalNumber < $this->getIntervalsNumber(); ++$intervalNumber) {
            $separator = $this->_findValueSeparator($intervalNumber, $interval);
            if (empty($separator)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->_quantileInterval[0] == 0) {
                $intervalFirstValue = $this->_values[0];
            }
            $separatorCandidate = false;
            $newIntervalFirstValue = $intervalFirstValue;
            $newLastSeparator = $lastSeparator;

            $valuesPerInterval = $this->_count / $this->_getCalculatedIntervalsNumber();
            while (!empty($separator) && !array_key_exists($intervalNumber, $result)) {
                $separatorsPortion = array_shift($separator);
                $bestSeparator = $this->_findBestSeparator($intervalNumber, $separatorsPortion);
                if ($bestSeparator && $bestSeparator[2] > 0) {
                    $isEqualValue = $intervalFirstValue ==
                    $this->_values[$bestSeparator[2] - 1] ? $this->_values[0] : false;
                    $count = $bestSeparator[2] + $this->_quantileInterval[0] - $lastCount;
                    $separatorData = [
                        'from' => $isEqualValue !== false ? $isEqualValue : $lastSeparator,
                        'to' => $isEqualValue !== false ? $isEqualValue : $bestSeparator[1],
                        'count' => $count,
                    ];
                    if (abs(1 - $count / $valuesPerInterval) <= self::INTERVAL_DEFLECTION_LIMIT) {
                        $newLastSeparator = $bestSeparator[1];
                        $newIntervalFirstValue = $this->_values[$bestSeparator[2]];
                        $result[$intervalNumber] = $separatorData;
                    } elseif (!$separatorCandidate || $bestSeparator[0] < $separatorCandidate[0]) {
                        $separatorCandidate = [
                            $bestSeparator[0],
                            $separatorData,
                            $bestSeparator[1],
                            $this->_values[$bestSeparator[2]],
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!array_key_exists($intervalNumber, $result) && $separatorCandidate) {
                $newLastSeparator = $separatorCandidate[2];
                $newIntervalFirstValue = $separatorCandidate[3];
                $result[$intervalNumber] = $separatorCandidate[1];
            }

            if (array_key_exists($intervalNumber, $result)) {
                $lastSeparator = $newLastSeparator;
                $intervalFirstValue = $newIntervalFirstValue;
                $valueIndex = $this->_binarySearch($lastSeparator);
                $lastCount += $result[$intervalNumber]['count'];
                if ($valueIndex != -1 && $lastSeparator > $this->_lastValueLimiter[1]) {
                    $this->_lastValueLimiter = [$valueIndex + $this->_quantileInterval[0], $lastSeparator];
                }
            }
        }
        if ($this->_lastValueLimiter[0] < $this->_count) {
            $isEqualValue = $intervalFirstValue == $this->_maxValue ? $intervalFirstValue : false;
            $result[$this->getIntervalsNumber()] = [
                'from' => $isEqualValue ? $isEqualValue : $lastSeparator,
                'to' => $isEqualValue ? $isEqualValue : ($this->_upperLimit === null ? '' : $this->_upperLimit),
                'count' => $this->_count - $lastCount,
            ];
        }

        return array_values($result);
    }

    /**
     * Get amount of segmentation intervals
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getIntervalsNumber()
    {
        if ($this->_intervalsNumber !== null) {
            return $this->_intervalsNumber;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * Find value separator for the quantile
     *
     * @param int $quantileNumber should be from 1 to n-1 where n is number of intervals
     * @param IntervalInterface $interval
     * @return array|null
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _findValueSeparator($quantileNumber, IntervalInterface $interval)
    {
        if ($quantileNumber < 1 || $quantileNumber >= $this->getIntervalsNumber()) {
            return null;
        }

        $values = [];
        $quantileInterval = $this->_getQuantileInterval($quantileNumber);
        $intervalValuesCount = $quantileInterval[1] - $quantileInterval[0] + 1;
        $offset = $quantileInterval[0];
        if ($this->_lastValueLimiter[0] !== null) {
            $offset -= $this->_lastValueLimiter[0];
        }
        if ($offset < 0) {
            $intervalValuesCount += $offset;
            $values = array_slice(
                $this->_values,
                $this->_lastValueLimiter[0] + $offset - $this->_quantileInterval[0],
                -$offset
            );
            $offset = 0;
        }
        $lowerValue = $this->_lastValueLimiter[1];
        if ($this->_lowerLimit !== null) {
            $lowerValue = max($lowerValue, $this->_lowerLimit);
        }
        if ($intervalValuesCount >= 0) {
            $values = array_merge(
                $values,
                $interval->load($intervalValuesCount + 1, $offset, $lowerValue, $this->_upperLimit)
            );
        }
        $lastValue = $this->offsetLimits($intervalValuesCount, $values);
        $bestRoundValue = [];

        if (count($values) > 0) {
            if ($lastValue == $values[0]) {
                if ($quantileNumber == 1 && $offset) {
                    $additionalValues = $interval->loadPrevious($lastValue, $quantileInterval[0], $this->_lowerLimit);
                    if ($additionalValues) {
                        $quantileInterval[0] -= count($additionalValues);
                        $values = array_merge($additionalValues, $values);
                        $bestRoundValue = $this->_findRoundValue(
                            $values[0] + self::MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE / 10,
                            $lastValue,
                            false
                        );
                    }
                }
                if ($quantileNumber == $this->getIntervalsNumber() - 1) {
                    $valuesCount = count($values);
                    if ($values[$valuesCount - 1] > $lastValue) {
                        $additionalValues = [$values[$valuesCount - 1]];
                    } else {
                        $additionalValues = $interval->loadNext(
                            $lastValue,
                            $this->_count - $quantileInterval[0] - count($values),
                            $this->_upperLimit
                        );
                    }
                    if ($additionalValues) {
                        $quantileInterval[1] = $quantileInterval[0] + count($values) - 1;
                        if ($values[$valuesCount - 1] <= $lastValue) {
                            $quantileInterval[1] += count($additionalValues);
                            $values = array_merge($values, $additionalValues);
                        }
                        $upperBestRoundValue = $this->_findRoundValue(
                            $lastValue + self::MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE / 10,
                            $values[count($values) - 1],
                            false
                        );
                        $this->_mergeRoundValues($bestRoundValue, $upperBestRoundValue);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $bestRoundValue = $this->_findRoundValue(
                    $values[0] + self::MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE / 10,
                    $lastValue
                );
            }
        }

        $this->_quantileInterval = $quantileInterval;
        $this->_values = $values;

        if (empty($bestRoundValue)) {
            $this->_skippedQuantilesUpperLimits[$quantileNumber] = $quantileInterval[1];

            return $bestRoundValue;
        }

        $valuesCount = count($values);
        if ($values[$valuesCount - 1] > $lastValue) {
            $this->_lastValueLimiter = [$quantileInterval[0] + $valuesCount - 1, $values[$valuesCount - 1]];
        }

        ksort($bestRoundValue, SORT_NUMERIC);
        foreach ($bestRoundValue as $index => &$bestRoundValueValues) {
            if (empty($bestRoundValueValues)) {
                unset($bestRoundValue[$index]);
            } else {
                sort($bestRoundValueValues);
            }
        }

        return array_reverse($bestRoundValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get quantile interval
     *
     * @param int $quantileNumber should be from 1 to n-1 where n is number of intervals
     * @return null|float[] [floatMin,floatMax]
     */
    protected function _getQuantileInterval($quantileNumber)
    {
        if ($quantileNumber < 1 || $quantileNumber >= $this->getIntervalsNumber()) {
            return null;
        }
        $quantile = $this->_getQuantile($quantileNumber);
        $deflectionLimit = floor($this->_count / 2 / $this->getIntervalsNumber());
        $limits = [
            min(floor($quantile - $deflectionLimit), floor($quantile)),
            max(ceil($quantile + $deflectionLimit - 1), ceil($quantile)),
        ];

        $sqrtParam = $this->_count * $quantileNumber * ($this->getIntervalsNumber() - $quantileNumber);
        $deflection = self::STANDARD_NORMAL_DISTRIBUTION * sqrt($sqrtParam) / $this->getIntervalsNumber();
        $left = max(floor($quantile - $deflection - 1), $limits[0], 0);
        if (array_key_exists($quantileNumber - 1, $this->_skippedQuantilesUpperLimits)
            && $left > $this->_skippedQuantilesUpperLimits[$quantileNumber - 1]
        ) {
            $left = $this->_skippedQuantilesUpperLimits[$quantileNumber - 1];
        }
        $right = min(ceil($quantile + $deflection), $limits[1], $this->_count - 1);

        return [$left, $right];
    }

    /**
     * Get quantile
     *
     * @param int $quantileNumber should be from 1 to n-1 where n is number of intervals
     * @return float|null
     */
    protected function _getQuantile($quantileNumber)
    {
        if ($quantileNumber < 1 || $quantileNumber >= $this->getIntervalsNumber()) {
            return 0;
        }

        return $quantileNumber * $this->_count / $this->getIntervalsNumber() - .5;
    }

    /**
     * Find max rounding factor with given value range
     *
     * @param float $lowerValue
     * @param float $upperValue
     * @param bool $returnEmpty whether empty result is acceptable
     * @param null|float $roundingFactor if given, checks for range to contain the factor
     * @return false|array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function _findRoundValue($lowerValue, $upperValue, $returnEmpty = true, $roundingFactor = null)
    {
        $lowerValue = round($lowerValue, 3);
        $upperValue = round($upperValue, 3);

        if ($roundingFactor !== null) {
            // Can't separate if values are equal
            if ($lowerValue >= $upperValue) {
                if ($lowerValue > $upperValue || $returnEmpty) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // round is used for such examples: (1194.32 / 0.02) or (5 / 100000)
            $lowerDivision = ceil(round($lowerValue / $roundingFactor, self::TEN_POWER_ROUNDING_FACTOR + 3));
            $upperDivision = floor(round($upperValue / $roundingFactor, self::TEN_POWER_ROUNDING_FACTOR + 3));

            $result = [];
            if ($upperDivision <= 0 || $upperDivision - $lowerDivision > 10) {
                return $result;
            }

            for ($i = $lowerDivision; $i <= $upperDivision; ++$i) {
                $result[] = round($i * $roundingFactor, 2);
            }

            return $result;
        }

        $result = [];
        $tenPower = pow(10, self::TEN_POWER_ROUNDING_FACTOR);
        $roundingFactorCoefficients = [10, 5, 2];
        while ($tenPower >= self::MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE) {
            if ($tenPower == self::MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE) {
                $roundingFactorCoefficients[] = 1;
            }
            foreach ($roundingFactorCoefficients as $roundingFactorCoefficient) {
                $roundingFactorCoefficient *= $tenPower;
                $roundValues = $this->_findRoundValue(
                    $lowerValue,
                    $upperValue,
                    $returnEmpty,
                    $roundingFactorCoefficient
                );
                if ($roundValues) {
                    $index = round(
                        $roundingFactorCoefficient /
                        self::MIN_POSSIBLE_VALUE
                    );
                    $result[$index] = $roundValues;
                }
            }
            $tenPower /= 10;
        }

        return empty($result) ? [1 => []] : $result;
    }

    /**
     * Merge new round values with old ones
     *
     * @param array &$oldRoundValues
     * @param array &$newRoundValues
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _mergeRoundValues(&$oldRoundValues, &$newRoundValues)
    {
        foreach ($newRoundValues as $roundingFactor => $roundValueValues) {
            if (array_key_exists($roundingFactor, $oldRoundValues)) {
                $oldRoundValues[$roundingFactor] = array_unique(
                    array_merge($oldRoundValues[$roundingFactor], $roundValueValues)
                );
            } else {
                $oldRoundValues[$roundingFactor] = $roundValueValues;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get intervals number with checking skipped quantiles
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getCalculatedIntervalsNumber()
    {
        return max(1, $this->getIntervalsNumber() - count($this->_skippedQuantilesUpperLimits));
    }

    /**
     * Get separator nearest to quantile among the separators
     *
     * @param int $quantileNumber
     * @param array $separators
     * @return array|false [deflection, separatorValue, $valueIndex]
     */
    protected function _findBestSeparator($quantileNumber, $separators)
    {
        $result = false;

        $i = 0;
        $valuesCount = count($this->_values);
        while ($i < $valuesCount && !empty($separators)) {
            $i = $this->_binarySearch($separators[0], [$i]);
            if ($i == -1) {
                break;
            }

            $separator = array_shift($separators);

            $deflection = abs(
                $quantileNumber * $this->_count -
                ($this->_quantileInterval[0] +
                    $i) * $this->_getCalculatedIntervalsNumber()
            );
            if (!$result || $deflection < $result[0]) {
                $result = [$deflection, $separator, $i];
            }
        }

        return $result ? $result : false;
    }

    /**
     * Search first index of value, that satisfy conditions to be 'greater or equal' than $value
     * Returns -1 if index was not found
     *
     * @param float $value
     * @param null|float[] $limits search [from, to]
     * @return int
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function _binarySearch($value, $limits = null)
    {
        if (empty($this->_values)) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (!is_array($limits)) {
            $limits = [];
        }
        if (!isset($limits[0])) {
            $limits[0] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($limits[1])) {
            $limits[1] = count($this->_values) - 1;
        }

        if ($limits[0] > $limits[1] || $this->_values[$limits[1]] < $value) {
            return -1;
        }

        if ($limits[1] - $limits[0] <= 1) {
            return $this->_values[$limits[0]] < $value ? $limits[1] : $limits[0];
        }

        $separator = floor(($limits[0] + $limits[1]) / 2);
        if ($this->_values[$separator] < $value) {
            $limits[0] = $separator + 1;
        } else {
            $limits[1] = $separator;
        }

        return $this->_binarySearch($value, [$limits[0], $limits[1]]);
    }

    private function offsetLimits($intervalValuesCount, $values)
    {
        if (array_key_exists((int)$intervalValuesCount - 1, $values)) {
            return $values[$intervalValuesCount - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have maintained two websites, for another website Algorithm.php not available in vendor path instead of that available in lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm.php, here how to can i assign my namespace?

Comment: probably you have downloaded the code from github. But it should work either in both cases.

Comment: Sorry, i can't get you, is it posible or not?

Comment: yes it is possible. no change in code.

Comment: How to edit namespace, my path lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Search/Dynamic

Comment: Above code should work in both websites. what changes you are expecting and in which file? for both the cases, namespace will be  `\Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm`.

Comment: Thank you it's working.

Comment: For knowledge, what is the difference between vendor and lib?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to see exactly what has fixed this error since the initial code isn't available anymore (https://paste.ofcode.org/eggKeUuvGeE3izxV6K9rUC), but for me what fixed the issue was extending the class the preference is for in the class class that replaces it.

As and example, the issue for me was that in my class declaration I had

```
class Algorithm
```

instead of

```
class Algorithm extends \Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm
```

As a rule of thumb then the new preference class should extend the class the preference is for in order to avoid the type error

Comment: Perfect Answer! To the point. The Rule of thumb you mentioned solved my issue. Thankyou